# postgresql returns null but mysql doesn't

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have an application for which I am migrating from Mysql to Psql.
I have three tables t1,t2,t3 described below . Table t3 will always have a entry as long as user is available , but both table t1 and t2 may or may not have entry if the user doesn't create DB in his account.

While executing q1 in mysql , I get result set containing values fetched from table t3, even if t1 and t2 doesn't have entry , but it returns null in psql . So I've written two queries pq1 and pq2 to be equivalent to q1 . What is the reason that mysql doesn't return null values but psql does? Is there any better solution to this than breaking down into two queries for psql ?

mysql query (q1)

```
select 
COALESCE(sum(dr.NO_OF_QT),0), 
ur.NO_OF_USERS, ur.NO_OF_DB, 0, 
COALESCE(sum(dr.NO_OF_SM),0),
COALESCE(sum(dr.NO_OF_RPTS),0)  
from DataBaseProps dr
left join DataBaseDetails db on dr.DB_ID=db.ID and db.STATUS=1
left join UserProps ur on db.OWNER_UID=ur.USER_UID
where ur.USER_UID='USER_UID'
```

Psql-query_1 (pq1)

```
select 
COALESCE(sum(dr.NO_OF_QT),0), 
0,0, 0, 
COALESCE(sum(dr.NO_OF_SM),0),
COALESCE(sum(dr.NO_OF_RPTS),0)  
from DataBaseProps dr
left join DataBaseDetails db on dr.DB_ID=db.ID and db.STATUS=1
left join UserProps ur on db.OWNER_UID=ur.USER_UID
where ur.USER_UID='USER_UID'
```

psql-query_2(pq2)

```
select NO_OF_USERS,NO_OF_DB from UserProps
where USER_UID='USER_UID'
```

Table 1 DataBaseProps (t1)

```
desc DataBaseProps >
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| DB_ID           | bigint(19) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| NO_OF_RPTS      | int(10)    | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| NO_OF_QT        | int(10)    | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| NO_OF_SM        | int(10)    | YES  |     | 0       |       |
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Table 2 - DataBaseDetails(t2)

```
 desc DataBaseDetails>
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+-----------------+-------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default         | Extra |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+-----------------+-------+
| ID                | bigint(19)   | NO   | PRI | NULL            |       |
| NAME              | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL            |       |
| STATUS            | int(10)      | NO   |     | 1               |       |
| OWNER_UID         | bigint(19)   | NO   |     | NULL            |       |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+-----------------+-------+
```

Table 3 UserProps(t3)

```
desc UserProps>
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| USER_UID        | bigint(19) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| NO_OF_DB        | int(10)    | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| NO_OF_USERS     | int(10)    | YES  |     | 0       |       |
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Your question mentions t1, t2, t3 but your example tables are dr, db, and ur, and it is not clear which is which. If they are in that order, then MySQL would not behave as you describe.

Comment: ur -> t3 (UserProps) , db-> t2 (DataBaseDetails) , dr-> t1 (DataBaseProps) . I have mentioned near database description.